# python tkinter text from serial

Tags: python, tkinter

I only started to learn how to build GUIs. I work with MAKE tkinter designer. I try to insert this while true code (works ok and print the data) to tkinter text. Can someone help for this?

```
while True:

    reading = ser.read(1)
    if reading == b'\x3b\x00\x00':
        reading = ser.read(22)
        if (reading[1:2]) == b'\x20':
            print("1: " + reading[6:].decode('utf-8',"ignore"))
        else:
            print("2: " + reading[6:].decode('utf-8',"ignore"))
            print("-------------------")
```

The support code:

```
    
portName = ""

def set_Tk_var():
    global port
    port = tk.StringVar()

def retrieve_input():
    global portName
    global fileName
    portName = "COM" + str(port.get())
    baudrate = 5208   
    ser = serial.Serial(portName,baudrate)
       
    root.mainloop()
   
def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, top_level, root
    w = gui
    top_level = top
    root = top

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import test1
    test1.vp_start_gui()
```

The tkinter code:

```
        self.comport = tk.Entry(self.comframe)
        self.comport.place(relx=0.155, rely=0.387,height=20, relwidth=0.108)
        self.comport.configure(background="white")
        self.comport.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.comport.configure(textvariable=test1_support.port)

        self.Button2 = tk.Button(self.comframe)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.168, rely=0.71, height=27, width=71)
        self.Button2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(command=lambda:test1_support.retrieve_input())
        self.Button2.configure(font="-family Arial -size 12 -")
        self.Button2.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button2.configure(text='''CONNECT''')
        

        self.Text1 = tk.Text(self.comframe)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.49, rely=0.258, relheight=0.413, relwidth=0.314)
        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(wrap="none")
```

The serial works ok .

Comment: I wonder why reading of 1 byte (`reading = ser.read(1)`) is used to compare with a 3-bytes data (`if reading == b'\x3b\x00\x00'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter and infinite while loops don't play well together. The GUI cannot update as the while loop is taking control.

Two methods exist.

1. Using a separate thread to deal with the serial comms
2. Using the `.after` method in tkinter to schedule a function which periodically reads from the serial port.

See this rough example below

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial

root = tk.Tk()


def updateSerial():
    reading = ser.read(1)
    #Rest of code here.
    root.after(500, updateSerial)

#Create your tkinter GUI Here

#Schedule the task to run after 500ms
root.after(500, updateSerial)

root.mainloop()
```